# Removing borders on custom buttons

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

I've written this small program which attempts to create a custom JButton unfortunately I can't manage to remove the border. I thought button.setBorder(null); would remove it but this has been ineffective. Does anyone know how to remove the border from the button so it's just the icon? Any help greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
package custombuttons;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CustomButtons {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomButtons h = new CustomButtons();
        h.setUp();
    }

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button;
    BufferedImage b;
    String toolTip = "Configure";

    public void setUp() {
        frame = new JFrame("Custom Buttons");
        try {
            b = ImageIO.read(CustomButtons.class.getResource("/images/config.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomButtons.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Image b1 = (Image) b;
        ImageIcon iconRollover = new ImageIcon(b1);
        int w = iconRollover.getIconWidth();
        int h = iconRollover.getIconHeight();
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        Image image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(iconRollover.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        ImageIcon iconDefault = new ImageIcon(b1);
        image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(iconRollover.getImage(), 2, 2, null);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIcon iconPressed = new ImageIcon(b1);

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setToolTipText(toolTip);
        button.setBorder(null);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setIcon(iconDefault);
        button.setRolloverIcon(iconRollover);
        button.setPressedIcon(iconPressed);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"a custom JButton"*  Why?  What does the custom button do (besides fail) that a standard button does not?

Answer (score 3):

have look at `button.setBorderPainted(false)` [more about JButton here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877817/714968)

Answer (score 0):

actually i tested your code on my Netbeans IDE and got no borders as you desire 
using only `button.setBorder(null);` or `button.setBorderPainted(false);` or `both of them` but 
i think you should make sure that your original image is really do not have any borders it self