# Change the color of a JButton in JGoodies WindowsLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jgoodies

How do I change the color of a JButton if I am using JGoodies `WindowsLookAndFeel`? After changing the color the button should still have some visual indication when it is clicked; the color gradient and click animation do not have to be the same as in JGoodies.

Using `setBackground()` and `setForeground()` only changes the color of the button outline and the button text:

```
import com.jgoodies.looks.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;
...

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowsLookAndFeel());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(50, 100);
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        button.setForeground(Color.RED);
        button.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like to set the color for the whole area of the button not just the outline. (This happens if the `WindowsLookAndFeel` is not used.)

I have also tried changing the colors in `com.jgoodies.looks.windows.WindowsBorders#getButtonBorder()` but this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: what windows version do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

Try adding call to setContentAreaFilled:

```
button.setContentAreaFilled(false); //must be before setOpaque
button.setOpaque(true);
```

or you can override JButton and paint:
[Change JButton gradient color, but only for one button, not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115672/change-jbutton-gradient-color-but-only-for-one-button-not-all)

Comment: That is pretty close to what I want (the color shows up correctly) but I get no visual indication of clicks when using `WindowsLookAndFeel` (I do when using the default look and feel).

Comment: Awarded the bounty since I did not add the visual indication stipulations until after I started the bounty.

Comment: Sry, have no time for research and test now.
Here some starting points:
0) http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4880747; 
1)  create you own ButtonUI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-a-custom-button-in-java-with-jbutton/5755124#5755124 ;
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043218/jbutton-background-images?rq=1 ; 
3) use images as background http://stackoverflow.com/a/11931487/5379032
4) WindowsXP - your code works correctly, no problem. Win8 - problem. Win7 not tested.