# Java JRE built-in image for testing purposes

Tags: java, image

Is there an image within the JRE that can be used for testing purposes?  I'm looking for either an Image, BufferImage or Icon object.  I did find a PNG file in the JRE path that I am currently using but looking to see what others have found or are using.

Comment: why do you need an image "within JRE" ?

Comment: So I don't have to rely on reading a PNG or JPG file from the file system.  I'm looking for a built-in image. Trying to see if others have discovered such an object.

Comment: how about create one using Java?

Comment: There are a number of icons in the JRE for the PLAFs.  E.G. as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877817/418556).  A new `BufferedImage` is as simple as `new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I currently do create one using Java from a PNG file in the JRE path.  I'm looking to see what others have found or are using.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Locations or Names?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Thanks...looking for those now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.  This code will generate a test image of any resolution.  It does not use a built-in image but I think this will work best for you.  Tweak as necessary to meet your needs.

```
static private Image createTestImage(final int resolution) {
    final Image image = new BufferedImage(resolution, resolution, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    final Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    final int points = (resolution * 72) / 96;
    g.setColor(new Color(.42f, .42f, 1.0f, .5242f));
    g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, points));
    g.drawString("!X!", 2, points);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(0, 0, image.getWidth(null) - 1, image.getHeight(null) - 1);
    g.drawOval(11, 11, image.getWidth(null) - 23, image.getHeight(null) - 23);
    g.drawOval(22, 22, image.getWidth(null) - 45, image.getHeight(null) - 45);
    return image;
}
```

Using

```
Image image = createTestImage(1024);
```

Produces a hi res image like:

[image]

Using

```
Image image = createTestImage(64);
```

Produces a lo res image like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS, there are a number of image files bundled with the JRE...

There are images in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\images\cursors` on Windows, and on Linux I found:

```
denis@laptop:~/Programs/jdk1.7.0_11/jre$ find | grep png
./lib/deploy/mixcode_s.png
./lib/images/icons/sun-java.png
./lib/images/icons/sun-java_HighContrast.png
./lib/images/icons/sun-java_HighContrastInverse.png
./lib/images/icons/sun-java_LowContrast.png
... (many others) ...
```