# How to set Jframe Background Image in GroupLayout Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, grouplayout

Am trying to set a background image for my frame but it does not work. I tried this link:

[Setting background images in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064977/setting-background-images-in-jframe)

The code:

```
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/Images/about.png")))));
```

I tried adding the above code to my Contentpane but it does not work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainMenu frame = new MainMenu();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainMenu() {
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MainMenu.class.getResource("/Images/bug-red.png")));
    setTitle("Automated Bug Fixing");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 712, 458);

            contentPane = new JPanel();

    //contentPane.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220));
    contentPane.setForeground(new Color(32, 178, 170));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
            *setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/Images/about.png")))));*
```

Comment: So, you've replaced one content pane with another....? What's not working?

Comment: am confused i just want to add the image in the background. If I do:
contentPane.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220)); It sets the background to grey. I want to add an image instead

Comment: Make sure your image is good - try an internal test image to verify. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377020/java-jre-built-in-image-for-testing-purposes/15410359#15410359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic concept looks fine.

The only possible reason you might be getting problems is if the image doesn't exist.

It looks look you are trying to reference an image that should exist within the context of the Jar

Instead of

```
ImageIO.read(new File("/Images/about.png"))
```

Try

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Images/about.png"))
```

Instead.

Also, don't swallow exceptions, make sure all exceptions are been logged at the very least

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BackgroundFrameImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BackgroundFrameImage();
    }

    public BackgroundFrameImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...))));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setContentPane(label);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    JLabel text = new JLabel("Hello from the foreground");
                    text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    text.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    frame.add(text);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException | HeadlessException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've an inkling the problem may lie with

```
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/Images/about.png")))));
```

Try removing the leading slash in the file path, as this may be interpreted differently based on the OS:

```
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("Images/about.png")))));
```

Comment: It works.fine now but it overwrites my Buttons etc..as MadProgrammer Suggested

Comment: *"removing the leading slash.. this may be interpreted differently based on the OS:"*  I've not encountered a case where it does, in my 10+ years of development.  The leading `/` on a file path indicates 'root of drive' as opposed to 'from current directory'.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was the case on non unix based systems... So you may very well be correct.

Comment: Actually, the slashes are incorrect in the dir. You want a \\ instead of a /.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything on an IPanel and put the IPanel on the JFrame.  Tweak as necessary to suit your needs.

```
public class IPanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image             imageOrg         = null;
private Image             image            = null;
{
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent e) {
            final int w = IPanel.this.getWidth();
            final int h = IPanel.this.getHeight();
            image = w > 0 && h > 0 ? imageOrg.getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH) : imageOrg;
            IPanel.this.repaint();
        }
    });
}

public IPanel(final Image i) {
    imageOrg = i;
    image = i;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (image != null)
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

Example:

```
    final JPanel j = new IPanel(image);
    j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    j.add(new JButton("YoYo"));
    j.add(new JButton("MaMa"));
    j.add(new JLabel(icon));
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: You might find [this](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) of interest