# GridBagLayout alignment and Button style

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to align a button using the `GridBagLayout` but it look I just can't achieve that. Also I want to remove the `JButton`'s texture from my custom button, but I can not.. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I want the buttons to be at the top( but using `GridBagLayout`) and also on the left and right margin of the green button there is the remains of the `JButton` style and I can't remove it completely.

Also, this is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestPanel{

    public TestPanel(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Panel1());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPanel();
    }


    public class Panel1 extends JPanel{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Panel1(){
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("Start.png");
            ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("Start-Pressed.png");
            JButton button = new JButton(im);
            JButton but = new JButton("BUT");
            button.setRolloverEnabled(true);
            Insets margin = new Insets(-15,-10,-10,-10);
            button.setBorderPainted(false);
            button.setMargin(margin);
            button.setRolloverIcon(i);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx=0.5;
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=0;
            add(button, c);
            c.gridx=2;
            c.gridy=1;
            add(but,c);

        }       
         }
          }
```

Edit:

```
c.gridy++;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.weighty = 1;
c.add(new JLabel(" "),c);
c.gridy++;
c.weighty = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
add(eButton, c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can achive it with help of dummy `JLabel` at bottom, like next(add to the end of constructor):

   ```
   c.gridy++;
   c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
   c.weighty = 1;
   add(new JLabel(" "), c);
   ```
2. To remove margin you can try [`setContentAreaFilled()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled(boolean)) method
3. Instead of `ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("Start.png");` use `ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(Panel1.class.getResource("Start.png"));`

Also see that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877817/2894369).

Comment: Why should i use ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(Panel1.class.getResource("Start.png")); ?

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Comment: I dont understand the code you wrote at point 1 ... i know that gridy++ will add row 1, fill vertical will make it stretch vertically and weighty =1 is giving space between rows. But i don't understand how i can put the button at let's say bottom, not top :-??

Comment: @AXL at point 1 adding label which grab all vertical space after components.  you need add dummy label at top/bottom/left/right to grab free space and to anchor components opposite;)

Comment: I know that, but i just dont understand how... i know that its because of fill,but i don't know about the others. Could you please check my edit ? This is what i tried ( adding the label at top and the button at bottom). But it doesnt work

Comment: You need to use `fill/weightx/weighty` together, change in edit last `weighty` to `c.weighty = 0;`. Also read [tutorial for `GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)